# Hide menu when clicked on (tablet)

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, toggle

I've made a small website-menu: http://website.coathings.nl/ (see it when resize the window). Works fine on desktop, but I need to dissappear when I click on in on phone or tablet. And I can't figure out how...

It needs to hide when the menu is open and you click on the menu-icon, a menu-item or somewhere else. And it needs to open when you click on the icon (when it's closed).

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve minimal, complete, and verifiable example. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your menu having class **"main-navigation"**

Use Media Query in CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Mobile phone generally have max width 640px on landscape mode. Thus for portrait and landscape mode below media query will work.

You can show the icon on mobile view. Apply a click event to the icon say 
and toggle the display property of menu from none to block and vise versa.

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
.icon{display:block;}
    .main-navigation { display:none }
    }
```

Eg: Suppose you call a function on click event. Check if menu is hidden or visible and based on that you hide show the menu.

```
function showMenu(){ //using jquery
    if($(".main-navigation").css("display") != "none"){
         $(".main-navigation").css("display","none")
    }else{
         $(".main-navigation").css("display","block");
    }

}
```

Comment: It allready shows up when I click on the icon, but it won't disappear when I click again on the icon (or on a menu item). And I really don't know how to make it work.

Comment: check the js logic added above.

Comment: Thank you, this is helping me a lot! When I click on the menu-item: the menu opens. And when I click again: the menu closes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS media queries to target certain device widths to target tablet users and change the CSS styling from there.

Considering this is WP, you would be best served by creating a child theme and editing the CSS from there.  You can see your themes in `wp-content/`